# Saving Firebase Data to Device

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to save whole Firebase data to device.
ValueListeners and ChildListeners have to be called a lot of times in the app. This becomes a little cumbersome. Sometimes it makes the app a little slow.

I know we can use setPersistenceEnabled, but in that case Listeners have to be called.

**So, is there any way, in which we can save data (database) in device in a way, from which accessing the data can be fast and easy?**

Answer (score 0):

The only way to get data from the server onto your device is by attaching a listener. But a convenient way to attach a listener without coding it yourself, is by calling `keepSynced(true)` on a reference or query. The SDK in that case attaches an empty listener to the node(s), so that the data in the cache stays up to date.